# Is it possible to add data to a DataTable event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Let's say I have a handler for `select`:

```js
table.on("select", function(e, dt, type, indexes){
    // do some stuff
}
```

and then later I manually trigger it with `someRow.select();`. Is it possible to either add a parameter to the handler, or add data to the event object? Something to the effect of..

```js
var e = jQuery.Event("select", {foo: "bar"});
someRow.trigger(e);
```

As to why, there's a snippet in the handler that I only want to fire on user row selects, but not on "manual" selects.

**EDIT:** Never mind, I moved that snippet to `user-select`. I'll leave the question posted out of curiosity though.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add second param (object or array) to `trigger`.

```
const table = $("#foo");
const data = {message: 'data can be array or object'};
table.trigger("select", data);
```

Another example from docs

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

[jQuery doc trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)